# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-reveal' this show me on my compiler in my react project ...what is this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-reveal

this error show me when I start "npm" start in my react project how can I solve this problem I tried but anything not works????

I have download npm packages react-reveal but still he shows me error and also I update npm and clear cache do lots of thigs but its not works

Comment: Could you show us what your `package.json` looks like, with a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `npm i react-reveal -f` to install it, then check if the `react-reveal` dependency is in the package.json. you might also what to check if you imported it right:

```
const Fade = require("react-reveal/Fade")
```